# Pandas Value_Counts Selection

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the output of the -

```
df['x'].value_counts()

-1    266551
 1    172667
 0    155994
```

I would like to calculate the maximum of the counts except of the value -1.

In this case, answer would be 172667.

How can i remove the value of -1 from it and select the max of other values?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop.html) + [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html):

```
df['x'].value_counts().drop(-1).max()
```

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series([266551,172667,155994], index=[-1,1,0])
print (s)
-1    266551
 1    172667
 0    155994
dtype: int64

print (s.drop(-1).max())
172667
```